# Excel VBA Else without if

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a if-function to distingiush between two sceneraios.

```
For Each Cell In Tabelle3.Range("A" & lastrow2)

Option A: If Cell <> "" Then run code
Option B: If Cell = "" Then skip this empty cell and go on with the next one
```

Here the whole code:

```
Sub IfFunction()

Dim lastrow2 As Long
lastrow2 = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myrange2 = Tabelle8.UsedRange


    For i = 2 To lastrow2

    For Each Cell In Tabelle3.Range("A" & lastrow2)

    If Cell = "" Then i = i + 1

    Else: i = i



        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange2, 3, False)



        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange2, 4, False)



        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 21) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange2, 5, False)

        Next i

    End If


End Sub
```

When I try to run this code, it does not execute because an error occurs that there is a 'ELSE without IF'-Function.

Does anyone know how I can use an IF-function here or what to use instead? Thanks. :)

Comment: Unrelated to your IF statement problem, you are missing and 'next cells'

Comment: @Jarom what exactly do you mean? Instead of "Next i"?

Comment: @HPM, see my answer

Comment: No, in addition to 'Next i' You have two loops in your code.  VBA needs to know when to go back to the beginning of each loop.  The 'Next' statement tells VBA to go to the beginning of the loop.  Your 'next i' statement tells VBA to go to the beginning of the inner loop.  You need a 'next cells' statement to tell VBA to go to the beginning of the 'For each' loop that goes through the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay that was actually way to simple :D I was running through the same column twice by

```
For Each Cell In Tabelle3.Range("A" & lastrow2)

If Cell = "" Then i = i + 1

Else: i = i
```

and

```
For i = 2 To lastrow2
```

Instead I can simply use:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow2

If Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1) <> "" Then



Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange2, 3, False)



Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange2, 4, False)



Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 21) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange2, 5, False)

End if
Next i
```

Thanks alot for your help & contribution!

Comment: that seems exactly what I noticed and amended in  my answer!  But your solution would skip two lines instead of the empty one only. try my code

Comment: you should really not use `i = i + 1` within a `For i` loop. you can just use `If Cell <> "" Then … End If` and put your code in between. So your code runs when the cell is NOT empty. Or you write `If Not Cell = "" Then` which also implies that the cell is not empty.

Answer (score 5):

if you continue writing after `Then` this means the `If` statement consists of one line only:

```
If Cell = "" Then i = i + 1 'End If automatically here
```

Then the `Else` has to be in that line too:

```
If Cell = "" Then i = i + 1 Else i = i 'End If automatically here
```

If you want to use a multi line `If` statement

```
If Cell = "" Then 
    i = i + 1
Else
    i = i
End If
```

---

#### But …

because `i = i` doesn't do anything you can just write

```
If Cell = "" Then i = i + 1
```

and omit the `Else` part completely because it does nothing at all.

---

#### And anther but …

because you are using a `For i` the `Next i` increments `i` automatically and you don't need to increment it yourself. There is no `i = i + 1` needed

Comment: @PEH: About your 2. But: Doesn't this imply that If the cell is empty it will run the code for this cell instead of skipping this cell and going on with the next cell?

Comment: @HPM No, you can just use `If Cell <> "" Then … End If` and put your code in between. So your code runs when the cell is NOT empty. Or you write `If Not Cell = "" Then` which also implies that the cell is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

your code has to `For` but one `Next` only, which would result in a syntax error

furthermore the `Next i` is intertwined with a `If-Then-Else` block code which would also result in a syntax error

finally I guess you're iterating twice along `Tabelle3` column A cells from row 2 to last not empty one, while you only need it once

Summing all that up, I'd say you can use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IfFunction()
    Dim myrange2 As Range, cell As Range
    Set myrange2 = Tabelle8.UsedRange

    With Tabelle3
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            cell.Offset(7, 18) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Offset(7), myrange2, 3, False)

            cell.Offset(7, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Offset(7), myrange2, 4, False)

            cell.Offset(7, 20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Offset(7), myrange2, 5, False)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```